# How to run a Dart Console Application?

Tags: dart

I just follow https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch01.html to run a Dart console application,but the result is ‘HTML file could not be found’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how to start it from DartEditor, just right-click the file in the `Files` view and choose `Run`. If you click the `Run` button in the toolbar, probably the previously launched file is launched (didn't use DartEditor since 1/2 year)

If you want to launch it from command line just run `dart bin/main.dart`

Comment: can you tell me the version of DartEditor what I can use

Comment: Any version should work this way. If you download the Dart from the www.dartlang.org website or install it using homebrew or apt-get you should be fine.